# How to fill Drop Down list Tree nested data using ajax in asp.net core project?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created an asp.net core MVC project. In my project, I've to used infinity category and subcategory. Right now I've done it. But I want to fetch nested JSON data(i mean category class) from the controller and show it in a dropdown list. So this is my question about how to fill the drop-down list tree with category class?

I've used Multi-Select Drop Down Tree Plugin you can see it by this link
**[Multi-Select Drop Down Tree Plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Drop-Down-Combo-Tree.html)**

```
 public class Category
        {

            public Category()
            {
                Categories = new List<Category>();
            }

            public int CategoryID { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Title")]
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }
            public int? ParenetCategoryID { get; set; }
            public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        }
```

---

```
public JsonResult FillDropdown()
 {
   return Json(_context.Categories.ToList());
 }
```

---

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-light">
            Fill Category
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label"></label>

                <input type="text" id="justAnInputBox" placeholder="Select" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="~/Drop-Down-Combo-Tree/icontains.js"></script>
<script src="~/Drop-Down-Combo-Tree/comboTreePlugin.js"></script>
<script>
         $(document).ready(function ($) {
        comboTree1 = $('#justAnInputBox').comboTree({
        source: $.ajax({
        url: "Categorys/FillDropdown",
        type: "Get",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
                }),
                isMultiple: false
               });
          });

       </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Multi-Select Drop Down Tree Plugin expects a data structure like below :

```
[
    {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Item 1 '
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Item 2',
        subs: [
            {
                id: 10,
                title: 'Item 2-1'
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

I create a new `DTO` class to hold the data :

```
public class CategoryDto{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public IList<CategoryDto> Subs{ get; set; }
}
```

We can convert `IList<Category>` to `IList<CategoryDto>` and then build them into CategoryDto trees :

```
public static class CategoryExtensions
{
    public static IList<CategoryDto> BuildTrees(this IList<Category> categories)
    {
        var dtos = categories.Select(c => new CategoryDto {
            Id = c.CategoryID,
            Title = c.CategoryName,
            ParentId = c.ParenetCategoryID,
        }).ToList();

        return BuildTrees( null, dtos);
    }

    private static IList<CategoryDto> BuildTrees(int? pid, IList<CategoryDto> candicates)
    {
        var subs = candicates.Where(c => c.ParentId== pid).ToList();
        if (subs.Count() == 0) {
            return new List<CategoryDto>();  // required an empty list instead of a null ! 
        }
        foreach (var i in subs) {
            i.Subs= BuildTrees(i.Id, candicates);
        }
        return subs;
    }
}
```

Now we can use the extension method to build trees in the `FillDropDown` action method :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FillDropdown()
{
    var categories= await _context.Category.ToListAsync();
    var trees = categories.BuildTrees();
    return new JsonResult(trees);
}
```

Lastly , use ajax to load it and set the categories :

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/category/filldropdown",
        type: "Get",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#justAnInputBox').comboTree({
                source:data,
                isMultiple:false,
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    })
});
```

I use following data to test it :

```
CategoryId CategoryName  ParentCategoryID
1          choice 1       NULL  
2          choice 2       NULL  
3          choice 3       NULL  
4          choice 4       NULL  
5          choice 2.1     2 
6          choice 2.2     2 
7          choice 2.3     2 
8          choice 2.2.1   6 
9          choice 2.2.2   6 
10         choice 2.2.3   6
```

And it works flawlessly :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. you did it very well.